# PKCE Workflow for getting RPT token requires clientSecret value

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

For web application development using Angular Framework. For authentication we are using the PKCE workflow using the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) library. And we are having no issues until we work authentication only for the FrontEnd.
In the Fine-Grained Authorization Implementation in our application we want to configure the authorization in our front-end client that we created in the KeyCloak. For that which we tried to enable the Authorization option for that client, The option cannot be enabled directly. This requires us to enable the 'Client Authentication' first as follows,

[image]

If we enable the 'Client Authentication' the access type is changed from 'public' to 'confidential', because of this change on the PKCE workflow on getting the token it is looking for 'clientSecret' which is not recommended for the web applications as part of security policy constraint.
This has been initiated as discussion as follows by June still there is no solution found.
[Keycloak Authorization with PKCE #21103](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/21103)

The authorization we are looking for in our application is as per our application requirement. So, we are looking for Authorization as independent to Client Authentication option during the PKCE workflow. Since it is tightly coupled in the latest versions of KeyCloak, we are not able to achieve the mentioned functionality.

Expected behavior
The 'Authorization' option can be enabled separately regardless of 'Client Authentication'.

Actual behavior
The 'Authorization' option cannot be enabled without enabling the 'Client Authentication' option.

Keycloak version
22.0.3

How to Reproduce?

1. Try to enable the 'Authorization' option under the 'Capability Config' section in client without enabling the 'Client Authentication'.
2. Register the angular application as client in the KeyCloak with public access type.
3. In angular application using the angular-oauth2-oidc library get the access token using the PKCE workflow.
4. Enable the Authorization to get the permissions configured for the web application client, without giving the client secret.